# What is the best way to initialize all the elements of a JTable with Clojure?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

Sorry if this is a bit of a noob question but I am still getting used to functional programming.

I want to write a simple Sudoku solver as an exercise.

One of my plans is to create a JTable with 9 rows and 9 columns and initialize them all with
the string "123456789" as a starting position.

If I have a TableModel I can define a function to initialize a single cell like this:

```
(defn initCell
 "inits a cell with 123456789"
 [dm row col]
 (doto dm (.setValueAt "123456789" row col)))
```

Now what is the most Clojure like way to get this called for all cells in the 9x9 table?

Comment: (.setValueAt dm ...) is equivalent to (doto dm (.setValueAt ....). doto is only useful for doing multiple operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly like this:

```
(doseq [x (range 10) y (range 10)]
  (initCell dm x y))
```